# Model's attributes are being failed validation when they are not passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Is it logical that when I don't pass attributes' values, they failed the validation of the custom validation method, even though I am not trying to update them, however, the value is valid, and it was created successfully at the first place.

```
   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "id"=>"2", "shop"=>{"allowed_users"=>"5"}, "commit"=>"עדכן"}
```

The validation fails only for the custom validation method, for :shop_customer_id.

Comment: What is the code of your custom validator?

Comment: That is not relevant, data are being validated correctly with new records, and when updating them when passing the parameters.

Comment: can you paste in your custom validation code ?